# Class existence and Reference count management

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I was told that a class doesn't really exist (in memory). What really exists are the objects. The class itself occupies no memory. I remember that from a book of Herbert Schildt (2002).

Now I am told, by C++Primer (2013), that each shared_ptr carries a counter that controls how many shared pointers point to the same address (reference count) and that

*"the class keeps track of how many share_ptrs point to the same object and automatically frees that object when appropriate".*

So, one book is telling about the "non-physical" existence of a class and another is telling that it "physically" exists because it seems to carry a variable or some data structure that stores the counting, therefore occupying memory, I assume.

Also, I don't really understand if that counter is only one, accessible in some way by every shared_ptr pointing to that address, or a number of counters equal to the number of shared_pointers pointing there. The last book says

*"we can think of a shared_ptr as if it has an associated counter".*

I was trying to create my own shared_ptr without using the Standard Library and I found out it was harder than I expected. Now I am just trying to understand what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: You're mistaken. The reference count of a `shared_ptr` is stored in a control block _object_ which is hidden from you.

Comment: It's also not generally true that a class doesn't take up memory, for example, member functions need to have a place in program memory, and static members do as well.

Comment: Thank you. Well, then  maybe C++Primer is mistaken.

Comment: People often use `class` interchangeably to mean a type and an instance of that type when talking about c++. Though only the first use is technically correct, don't be surprised if you encounter the second form. Alternatively, when talking about the behavior of a class, it refers to the behavior of the instances of the class.

Comment: I agree, 'class' in the quote from C++Primer is probably to be interpreted as _instances of_ a class.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` has one control block (which includes the pointer counter) per managed object.

Comment: Yeah, that must be the reason: the use of "class" word referring to an instance instead of an actual class. Also, very interesting the fact that member functions and static variables occupy memory. An the control block is really the key for the reference count. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the class keeps track of how many share_ptrs point to the same object and automatically frees that object when appropriate"

This might be something that slipped through proofreading. On the other hand, it is accurate from the perspective where objects are data and classes are behavior. Objects occupy memory and have addresses. Classes have logic and instructions. Keeping track of something and freeing something are behaviors, so they originate from the class. (The tracking would be recorded within the object, but the logic for deciding what gets stored lies in the class. It's a fine point. You should not spend too much time on it.)

> Also, I don't really understand if that counter is only one, accessible in some way by every shared_ptr pointing to that address, or a number of counters equal to the number of shared_pointers pointing there.

There would be only one counter (the alternative would add overhead with no benefit). One way this could be implemented is by double indirection. The smart pointer could point to a helper object that contains the counter and the pointer that you are interested in.

smart pointer -> control block -> your data